# Prolog, how to ask if something exists given only partial information?

Tags: prolog

I have a list of flights and cities that I want to search to see if there is the possibility of flying from one to the other. I define my cities as such

```
city(city1).
city(city2).
...
```

all the way up to city5, and I define my flights as such

```
...
flight( city4, city5, 14:00, 15:00).
flight( city4, city5, 16:00, 17:00).
...
```

I want to ask prolog if there exists a flight from a start city to a end city, ignoring the times.

I've tried

```
flight(city1, city2, !, !)
```

and I am told false, isn't `!` the wildcard symbol?

Comment: No, `!` is definitely not a wildcard symbol in prolog. Not sure where you heard that. You can use a string starting with `_` such as `_` itself or `_Time` etc.

Comment: Searching "prolog wildcard" brought up a stack post with the `!` in it with some Prolog jargon that I thought meant wildcard.

Comment: Ah I spotted that, too. It wasn't a very well-worded posting. I think they were asking about their predicate with the `_` in it. The problem turned out to be related to the cut (`!`) operator they were using. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `_` symbol for wildcard arguments. Try this:

```
flight(city1, city2, _, _)
```

You also can always try it with variable names to let the interpreter find the matches:

```
flight(city1, city2, D, A)
```

or something along those lines.